# Allowing user to skip multi-factor authentication for 30 days from a device

Tags: django, session

I've inherited an app at my company (ReactJS/Django), and they've asked me to implement multi-factor authentication. I've got it wired up with django-mfa, and the authentication works great. Now, they've requested that if a user logs in with MFA, they will not be asked for MFA again on THAT device for 30 days.

At first, I thought no problem. You can do it with a cookie or whatever as you would any persistent session, and instead of using that to keep the user logged in, you can use it to determine whether or not to ask for MFA verification.

The obvious oversight I made in my haste is that *theoretically* you could have multiple users logged in to that same device. User A could log in with MFA. If you store a cookie with session information that allows User A to skip MFA, what happens when User B logs in?

I don't really know any obvious way around this. Is there a straight-forward or conventional way to manage multiple user sessions in a browser, or an alternative approach to this problem I'm missing?